# HttpCallout to external Worldline API authenticaion not working but same call working frrom Postman

Tags: httprequest, authorization

I'm currently working on interactions from SFDC to Worldline APIs and I have an issue with the authentication to their API. I have followed what they wrote [here](https://support.direct.ingenico.com/en/documentation/api/authentication#authentication_authenticate_without_sdks_new) and the generated authorization header format is identical to what gets generated in the public Postman Worldline collection, but I get the 403 status code, and in Postman it works fine.

My static method gets called inside an

My Apex code looks like this:

```java
public with sharing class GenerateWorldlineAuthorization {
    //GET Http Callout for Worldline Authorization
    public static String getWorldlineAPIAuthorization() {
        Http httpCall = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        String apiKey = 'ABCDEFGH11112233FGTY';
        String apiSecret = 'ADFGC56DSFSDAD89PLI/GHTERRERADSADAD4554GHFFD==';
        String pspId = 'userpspId';
        String stringToHash;
        String requestMethod = 'GET';
        String contentType = '';
        String hostname = 'payment.preprod.direct.worldline-solutions.com';
        String uriResource = '/services/testconnection';
        String endpointURL = '/v2/' + pspId + uriResource;
        String currentTime = '';
        String encodedSignature = '';
        String authorizationValue = '';
        String responseString = '';
        Datetime currentDateTime = Datetime.now();

        currentTime = currentDateTime.format('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT';

        if (requestMethod != 'GET') {
            contentType = 'application/json';
        }

        stringToHash = requestMethod + '\n' + contentType + '\n' + currentTime + '\n' + endpointURL + '\n';

        System.debug(stringToHash);

        Blob stringToHashBlob = Blob.valueOf(stringToHash);
        String encodedHash = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(stringToHashBlob);
        Blob encodeHashBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedHash);
        Blob apiSecretBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(apiSecret);
        Blob hmacSHA256blob = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',encodeHashBlob,apiSecretBlob);
        Blob signature = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA256', hmacSHA256blob);

        encodedSignature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signature);
        authorizationValue = 'GCS v1HMAC:' + apiKey + ':' + encodedSignature;

        httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://' + hostname + endpointURL);
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        httpRequest.setHeader('Date', currentTime);
        httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationValue);
        httpRequest.setHeader('Host', hostname);
        httpRequest.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
        httpRequest.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpCall.send(httpRequest);

        System.debug('Authorization:' + httpRequest.getHeader('Authorization'));
        System.debug('Date:' + httpRequest.getHeader('Date'));
        System.debug('Host:' + httpRequest.getHeader('Host'));

        System.debug('https://' + hostname + endpointURL);
        System.debug('Response: ' + httpResponse.getBody());

        responseString = 'Response code: '+ String.valueOf(httpResponse.getStatusCode()) + '. Response Status: ' + httpResponse.getStatus();

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

```java
public with sharing class CreateWorldlinePayment {
    //Method that calls the authorization fpr the Worldline APIs
    @Future(Callout=true)
    public static void getPaymentGatewayAuthorization() {
         String paymentAuthorizationResponse = GenerateWorldlineAuthorization.getWorldlineAPIAuthorization();

        System.debug(paymentAuthorizationResponse);
    }
}
```

```java
trigger CardPaymentTrigger on Asset (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            for (Asset asset : Trigger.new) {
                CreateWorldlinePayment.getPaymentGatewayAuthorization();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the apikey and secret code from the Question.

Comment: @SarojBera, those are dummy values. I wouldn't put the real ones in a public place.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it seems I was doing to much. So, instead of writing

```
 Blob stringToHashBlob = Blob.valueOf(stringToHash);
    String encodedHash = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(stringToHashBlob);
    Blob encodeHashBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedHash);
    Blob apiSecretBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(apiSecret);
    Blob hmacSHA256blob = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',encodeHashBlob,apiSecretBlob);
    Blob signature = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA256', hmacSHA256blob);
```

, all I needed to write was

```
Blob hmacSHA256blob = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(stringToHash),Blob.valueOf(apiSecret));
encodedSignature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacSHA256blob);
```

and it worked.

Hope this helps anybody who faces similarr problems in the future.